# Android: Delete button with handler message

Tags: android, button, handler, message

I want to delete a button which I pressed. Since I create all my buttons in the soundButtonGenerator-function I can't use:

```
View view = ((GridLayout)soundButton.getParent()).findViewById();
            ((GridLayout)soundButton.getParent()).removeView(view);
```

For finding the pressed button and delete it. I think I can use handler-messages in order to find the button and delete it...?

```
public void soundButtonGenerator() {

    GridLayout layout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.GL);
    layout.setColumnCount(3);
    layout.setRowCount(3);

    Point size = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;
    int soundButtonWidth = (int)(screenWidth * 0.3);
    int soundButtonHeight = (int) (screenHeight * 0.2);

    final GradientDrawable button_press_false = new GradientDrawable();
    final GradientDrawable button_press_true = new GradientDrawable();
    button_press_false.setColor(Color.parseColor("#022864"));
    button_press_false.setCornerRadius(15);
    button_press_false.setStroke(6, Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    button_press_true.setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
    button_press_true.setCornerRadius(15);
    button_press_true.setStroke(6, Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    for (int i = 0; i < soundList.size(); i++) {

        final Button soundButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());

        soundButton.setId(i);
        idList.add(soundButton.getId());
        soundButton.setText(nameList.get(i));
        soundButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        soundButton.setWidth(soundButtonWidth);
        soundButton.setHeight(soundButtonHeight);
        soundButton.setBackgroundDrawable(button_press_false);

        layout.addView(soundButton);

        soundButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    sp.play(soundList.get(v.getId()), 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                    soundButton.setBackgroundDrawable(button_press_true);
                    soundButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

                    handle.sendMessage(soundButton); // <---------------
                    handle.postDelayed(deleteButton, 1000); // If you press the button for 1000 ms, go to the deleteButton-thread.

                    return true;
                }else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    soundButton.setBackgroundDrawable(button_press_false);
                    soundButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
                    handle.removeCallbacks(deleteButton);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This function is called when you press the button for 1000 ms:

```
Runnable deleteButton = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       /* Obtain the sent message, find the pressed button and delete it! */
    }
};
```

**Summary:**
 - Press button for 1000 ms
 - Find the button.
 - Delete the button!
 4. Delete it!

Comment: What exactly is your error or problem?

Comment: @Knossos: I want to delete a button which I pressed, using the run method in the bottom of the question.

Comment: ... Then do it. You seem to have the code figured out. What is the actual question?

Comment: It's the connection between sending the pressed button and deleting in the run function. 

 handle.sendMessage(soundButton); <--- send the button to run-thread (doesn't work).

Comment: @Wickerman:  Current code is deleting button or not?

Comment: It doesn't, need some guidance how to find and delete the pressed button from the run-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to delete a button which I pressed

Use class constructor for getting pressed button in `run` method of Runnable as:

**1.** Create a inner class by implementing Runnable :

```
 class DeleteButtonClass implements Runnable{
  private View clickedButton
  DeleteButtonClass(View clickedButton){
   this.clickedButton=clickedButton;
  }  
  @Override
    public void run() {
        GridLayout layout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.GL);
        layout.removeView(clickedButton); //<< remove view here
    }

  }
```

**2.** Now create object of DeleteButtonClass class by passing `v` which is first parameter of `onTouch` method or `soundButton` :

```
DeleteButtonClass objDeleteButtonClass=new DeleteButtonClass(v);
handle.postDelayed(objDeleteButtonClass, 1000);
```

Comment: Seems like a good solution, but the removeView can't be resolved?